# Expressions: a get-by-ID-selector when I have the Expression to get the ID?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

I have a generic base repository class for LINQ-to-Entities that can do things like selecting an entity based on the ID.

In order to subclass it, you need to implement these two:

```
protected override Expression<Func<User, bool>> GetByIDSelector(int id)
{
  return u => u.UserID == id;
}

protected override Expression<Func<User, int>> KeySelector
{
  get { return u => u.UserID; }
}
```

I would like to just have the `KeySelector` (which is used for default sort order).

My 'get by ID' method looks like this:

```
public virtual TDataModel GetByID(TKey id)
{
  var entity = SetProvider.Set<TDataModel>().Where(GetByIdSelector(id)).SingleOrDefault();

  if (entity == null)
  {
    throw new EntityNotFoundException<TDataModel>(id);
  }

  return entity;
}
```

Where `GetByIdSelector` looks like this, which should turn the `KeySelector` expression into one that can select by ID.

```
private Expression<Func<TDataModel, bool>> GetByIdSelector(TKey id)
{
  return Expression.Lambda<Func<TDataModel, bool>>
  (
    Expression.Equal(KeySelector.Body,
    Expression.Constant(id)), 
    KeySelector.Parameters.Single()
  );
}
```

However, the Entity Framework throws an exception that the parameter passed in by that isn't bound to the query.

> The parameter 'u' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression.

Is there any way I can *cleanly* reuse the `KeySelector` Expression without having to rebuild the entire thing?

Comment: Is `TDataModel` a type-parameter of the base-class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because every time you call `this.KeySelector`, it's creating a brand new lambda expression (hence the call to `KeySelector.Parameters.Single()` is not the same parameter as the parameter used for `KeySelector.Body`).  Cache that expression into a variable as follows and it will work.

```
private Expression<Func<TDataModel, bool>> GetByIdSelector(TKey id)
{
    var keySelector = KeySelector;
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TDataModel, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            keySelector.Body,
            Expression.Constant(id)
        ), 
        keySelector.Parameters.Single()
    );
}
```

What I would probably do is rather fix the code in the KeySelector property to use a fixed value such that the value retrieved is always the same instance.

Example:

```
private static readonly Expression<Func<User, int>> _keySelector = u => u.UserID;

protected override Expression<Func<User, int>> KeySelector
{
    get { return _keySelector; }
}
```

Then if you do that - your old code for GetByIdSelector is actually no worse than my version above.

Comment: I spent a good hour or so trying to figure this one out. Thank you!